# Include Twig File Without Giving File Extension

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension

I am new to twig template engine. I am trying to include  some twig file inside another twig file. I am using the following code to include it,

```
{% include 'layout/css.html.twig' %}
```

But for all inclusion i want to include the file without giving extension in it. Where should do that configuration to use the above inclusion like below?

```
{% include '/twig/front/layout/css' %}
```

Comment: Why? You could write a custom twig function.